# Clients can't connect to owncloud

Tags: server, owncloud-server

I recently installed a owncloud server on a remote computer. The owncloud Client software is in sync with the server.

But Nautilus, Thunderbird Lightning or evolution can't connect to the DAV resources. The server doesn't seem to accept my password.

The version is ownCloud 6.0.1+dfsg-1ubuntu1 (Debian) (stable) for owncloud and ubuntu 14.04 for the server (and the client computer).

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe it was a problem with my password. Another test account with a very simple password (without any special characters) was able to log in.

Answer (score 1):

It really seems to be a problem with an [umlaut](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/umlaut) (a mark in German). It appeared only when I tried to login via firefox.

It appears that it is more a problem with firefox than with owncloud. I had a similar problem with the CUPS webinterface. Also solved by a new password without umlauts.